# Rendering the HTML's of different controller in the single (caller) view in RAILS 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have link in a view , href on this link points to an action in a different controller.
What I need is when I click the link I need the view corresponding to  a different controller to be rendered in my first views div.

eg:
I have a menu list in the left side of the page and a content div in the rightside of the page. Each of the left side menu corresponds to actions/views in different controllers.
when I click on any of the left side links it should render the respective htmls from that controller, in my right side div.

Thanks

Comment: Simple task use ajax and do it.

Comment: Is it possible to send html  content back to the ajax caller as a response.                                                               respond_to do |format|
      // Can i send the html present in my view back to the ajax caller
    end

Comment: I thing you didn't know the flow of rails with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The rails-y way of doing this is to use the remote: true option in your link_to. Setup the controller to respond to format.js, and setup a js.erb template to replace said content.

```
<%= link_to 'Page 2', page_2_path, remote: true %>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def page_2

  end
end
```

Views:

```
# pages/_page_2.html.haml
<h1>Some content</h1>

# pages/page_2.js.erb
$('.container').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'pages/page_2')) %>');
```

For the menu/page content feel you're looking for, Rails 4's turbolinks give a pretty good feel for what you want to achieve.